How do I use the BulkExport API to retrieve all messages for a specific dat
Using the BulkExport API and examples, I am unable to retrieve all messages for a given day.
I'm using Postman, to test on.
I know that I am authenticated, because I can change the authentication parameters, and it will fail.
How does the API determine which Message Service I am referring to?
We are not on an Enterprise plan.
The url I have created is: https://bulkexports.twilio.com/v1/Exports/Messages/Days/2024-10-21
However, I receive the following response:
{
    "code": 20404,
    "message": "The requested resource /Exports/Messages/Days/2024-10-21 was not found",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404",
    "status": 404
}


Twilio Evangelist here,
The error: 20404 is usually received in the BulkExport API when there's not a valid job. According to the following API documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/bulkexport, in order to fetch data, it's needed to create a job like this:
curl -X POST "https://bulkexports.twilio.com/v1/Exports/Messages/Jobs" \

--data-urlencode "Email=example@example.com" \

--data-urlencode "WebhookMethod=POST" \

--data-urlencode "WebhookUrl=https://webhook.site" \

--data-urlencode "StartDay=2022-11-05" \

--data-urlencode "EndDay=2022-11-06" \

--data-urlencode "FriendlyName=Export1" \

-u 'ACxxx:12345'

It takes some minutes to create the Job, you will see the expected time in the property estimated_completion_time. Additionally, you should expect an update when your Job is ready within the included "WebhookUrl" or "Email"
Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/bulkexport/export-custom-job
Once your Job is ready, please execute this command:
curl -X GET "https://bulkexports.twilio.com/v1/Exports/Messages/Days/2022-11-05" \
-u 'ACxxx:12345'

You will see a URL, please copy it and paste it in your browser, the download will start after that.
Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/bulkexport/day
Regarding the following inquiry: How does the API determine which Message Service I am referring to? We are not on an Enterprise plan. The API uses the Messaging Service configured as default.
I hope this way you're able to retrieve data with the BulkExport API.

Thank you SebastianCS!! I was off to a rough start but am catching hang of things. I was able to get it going, thanks for your assistance.
Duane
